# О сложности русского языка

Tags: лингвистика

Случайно наткнулся в сети на обсуждение вопроса "Почему русский язык такой сложный?" И, честно говоря, внятного ответа там никто так и не дал - сплошные рассуждения ни о чем. А ведь действительно - русский язык считается для изучения иностранцами одним из самых сложных. Интересно, с чем это связано? Я слышал, что все языки развиваются по принципу упрощения: например, латинская грамматика сложнее итальянской, а древнерусский намного сложнее современного русского. Можно ли объяснить сложность русского языка его некоторым консерватизмом (в хорошем смысле этого слова)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мои соображения на этот счёт.
Во-первых, русский язык синтетический (в отличие от английского, например), что обуславливает большое число словоформ и более-менее свободный порядок слов в предложении. Во-вторых, в русском языке много слов-синонимов, часто ощутимо отличающихся по оттенкам значений. Одновременно с этим стоит отметить несколько ярко выраженных стилистик со своими особенностями. В-третьих, обилие приставок и суффиксов. В-четвёртых, часто встречающиеся шипящие и свистящие фонемы, а также подвижное ударение, от которого нередко зависит смысл слова.

Answer (score 2):

Да какой уж там консерватизм.  Это один из самых быстро развивающихся языков, более 200 тысяч словарных единиц, и это только у Даля. Количество отечественных работ по языку значительно опережает, вместе взятое, на западе, относительно их собственных языков. Сюда надо включить и работы по всем славянским языкам.

Впитывает  и обрабатывает кучу  заимствований, иначе бы и споров, на наших форумах, постоянных не было.  И потом, пойдите найдите язык, у которого только общепринятых норм литературного, было бы столько слов. О какой консервации идет речь? Другое дело, что при изучении импортный народ не окунается с головой в колодец, пытается по верхам понять суть языка, штамп, очевидный при изучении всех западно-европейских языков. Море одинаковых корней и все просто. А у нас в каждом слове есть потаенный, веками наработанный смысл, который не доступен иностранцу современному, и он уже не просто так, а и в генах. Именно поэтому потомки русских, только попав в среду русскоговорящих, сразу врубаются.
Менталитет, не пустое слово.
Если и найдутся противники такой позиции, я им отвечу, в западных языках гораздо больше заимствований из русского  "славянского", чем они думают.  А анализ показывает, что вообще эти языки тянуты из русского -- "славянского", причем склонность к упрощению понятна. Как говорит Задорнов -- тупые. Хотя я его не поощряю. Он самоупростился. По верхам бегает с историей и лингвистикой.
Но история как раз и  вырисовывается из языков, а не из всяких фантазмов монахов, писавших летописи и чего еще там. Придумать можно, а вот язык хранит то, что не придумали, веками.
И более того, работы Фоменко с Носовским в корне обнажили истоки официальной истории, дутой от монахов и церкви. А анализ языков только подтверждает это в полной мере.
Частности - отдельная тема. Суть: русско-"славянское"  присутствие обнаруживается во всех языках как Европы, так и Азии. Оно на пустом месте возникнуть не могло, а это значит носители языка присутствовали на территориях, и в немалом количестве. И тем или иным способом растолковали местным значения слов.  К примеру, латынь стручок гороха -- пися, окученная русскими словами вдоль и поперек. Вплоть до оружия, гладиус -- гладкий.

Не в жизь не поверю, что мы произошли от латинян. И их язык - основа нашего.

Answer (score 2):

**Отзывы иностранцев о русском языке (материал из Сети)**

**Русский язык не для слабаков.** Он постоянно мотивирует совершенствоваться и расширять свой кругозор. Иностранцы, полюбившие русский язык, признают, что он для них является неким вызовом.

В русском языке огромное количество слов и морфем, обозначающие **самые тонкие оттенки речи.** Никаким другим языком планеты невозможно так точно передать малейшие особенности информации.
Так, если в немецком "мужчина" всегда der Mann, то в русском есть и мужчина, и мужчинка, и мужик, и мужичок. От всего этого лексического разнообразия у иностранцев тоже волосы дыбом встают.

В общем, дело тут все кроется в необычайной тонкости русского языка, **его поэтичности, особенности.** Давайте же гордиться тем, что мы с вами говорим и пишем именно на русском — одном из сложнейших и прекраснейших языков мира!

**Я видел твердый знак,** когда изучал алфавит, а потом он не встречался мне в словах около года и я про него забыл. И когда профессор увидел, в какое замешательство я пришел, когда обнаружил эту букву, он сказал: «Изучая русский язык, **будьте готовы постоянно удивляться».**

Как-то на лекции я сказала учительнице из Британии, что у нас в алфавите есть две буквы, которые **не имеют звука (ь и ъ)**. Но в больший шок она пришла после того, когда я добавила, что при чтении они **произносятся**.

Я не понимаю, как можно **произнести звук «оо».** Например, в словах «сообщения» или «тихоокеанский».

Энтузиазм выучить русский моего друга-испанца разбивается о попытки **воспроизвести Ы.** Он говорит, что механизм произнесения этого звука — **вне его разумения.**

Знакомый британец (преподаватель английского) сказал, что не в первый раз замечает такую вещь: русские понимают лишь в том случае, если иностранец говорит **на «angry Russian» («злой русский»),** если сказать спокойным и мягким тоном, то вас не поймут.  **Интонация!

Речь идет о **повышение тона** в середине предложения. Им кажется, что мы на них кричим.  Не понять иностранцу **мелодику** русской речи!

Самым смешным «словом» для британцев **оказалось «потому что»,** и однажды они попросили объяснить значение этого слова. Оказалось, что «потому что» им слышится как одно слово «патамушта» и они думали, что это что-то вроде **шаманского проклятия или вызова духа из преисподней.**

```
такая портянка, много слов, а по-сути написано мало, 
какого хрена? Неуважение к читателю. stackexchange 
растет из stackoverflow, где инженеры отвечают друг 
другу кратко и лаконично, а не несут пургу про 
славян и колодец.
```

**Лаконичен ли наш язык?** Давайте сравним. Попробуйте сказать иностранцу на английском языке: Привет, я Крис". Обычно реакция такая: "Привет, мы с вами знакомы?" Или: Не могу ли я чем-нибудь помочь вам?" И только русские отвечают: **"Привет! И что?"** Куда же **лаконичнее**!)

Но те, кто не сдаются, должны запастись терпением, ведь впереди **грамматика.** И вот тут иностранцы думают, что они **слишком логичны для того, чтобы овладеть русским языком.** Действительно, в эти моменты чувствуется вся **древность русского языка,** ведь объяснить грамматику какой-то логической закономерностью практически невозможно. Всё уже давно запуталось и многократно реформировалось. **Одни слова** имеют похожее значение, но разные корни, **а другие** имеют разное значение, но похожее написание.

Полнейший хаос? **Нет, не хаос.** Но гармонию  русской речи можно понять далеко не сразу и не всем.

Comment: Одна из самых больших проблем, что в английском происходящее рассматривается через призму явлений и свойств - что чем является, а в русском через обладание, имение, через то, что есть. То есть, вот лежит на столе яблоко. В английском - это две условности, стол и яблоко, ну и одно на другом лежит, то есть покоится. А в русском нужно сказать чей стол и чьё яблоко, чтобы стало понятно, о чём речь. Либо это будет разговор о физике и двух объектах. Но опять же, яблоко и стол относятся к физике. Ну и яблоко по английски даже не яблоко, а единичный объект обладающий свойством яблок.

Comment: Интонация же дает возможность понять, о чьём столе и чьём яблоке идет речь. Принадлежат ли они говорящему или нет, например. В английском же яблоко принадлежит не кому-то, а чему-то - яблокам, яблоневым деревьям, и  т.д., а стол к мебели. В русском же стол может еще принадлежать сам себе, то есть идее стола, а не идее мебели, потому что у мебели нет идеи, у неё есть только функция.

Comment: Кстати, подумал сегодня, что в английском вообще нельзя начать утверждение с глагола, а в русском можно, причем такие, к которым и вопрос не задашь. В английском с вспомогательного глагола начинаются вопросы.

Answer (score 1):

В дополнение к изрядному количеству архаики, русский язык вобрал в себя множество категорий и форм, типичных для финно-угорских языков, весьма отличающихся от большинства западных.

Всё вместе (индоевропейская архаика плюс финно-угорская экзотика) создаёт множество исключений и когнитивный диссонанс при соприкосновении с "матричной картиной мира", привычной для говорящих на большинстве западных языков.

А именно:

1. Категория [эвиденциальности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C).
2. [Парциальное](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2) управление некоторых глаголов.
3. Фактически - большее, чем представлено в ломоносовской грамматике, [количество падежей](http://slavikap.livejournal.com/17796461.html).
4. Категория одушевлённости-неодушевлённости.
5. [Модальность](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_(%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)), выражаемая лексически (а не глаголами, как в большинстве европейских языков).
6. Модальность, выражаемая интонационно (а опять-таки не глаголами).
7. [Супплетивизм](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC) (не самая большая редкость в языке, но не единственная).
8. Категория определённости-неопределённости выражена неявно.
9. Множество [эллипсисов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81), большинство из которых ещё и модально.
10. Чередование согласных.
11. [Элизия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%8F) гласных.
12. Сам по себе кириллический алфавит тоже не очень прост (например, если вы научились читать печатные буквы, то потом нужно заново учиться рукописным).
13. [Топиковость синтаксиса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B8) (википедия говорит, что русский язык - не топиковый, но это не так. При этом топиковость может быть эллипсной - то есть мало того, что порядок слов определяется тем, о чём говорится в предложении - он ещё и может определяться тем, о чём ***не*** говорится).
14. Конструкции типа "ревмя реветь", "бежмя/бегмя бежать" и так далее.
15. Двойное отрицание (ну и известный анекдот про [двойное согласие](http://pikabu.ru/story/russkiy_yazyik_unikalen_1698244) с примером пресловутой модальности).
16. Нет универсальных вежливых обращений к незнакомому лицу.
17. "Славянский счёт" (до четырёх предметы считаются в единственном числе, от пяти - во множественном, а слово "год" или "человек" - это ещё и плюс супплетивизм).
18. Конструкция "у меня есть" - то есть когда говорится о том, что некто чем-то владеет - образуется без помощи глагола "иметь" (в противоположность тому, как, опять-таки, бывает в большинстве западных языков).
19. При этом глагол "быть" в предыдущей конструкции - он может использоваться, а может пропускаться, и таким образом выражается определённость или неопределённость.
20. Слова с мягким знаком на конце (если это не образованные от прилагательных абстрактные термины) нужно заучивать по грамматическому роду.
21. Большой процент исконной лексики (особенно в глаголах) вместо привычных интернациональных слов. Причём даже на бытовом уровне: холодильник, свет, сеть, стол, окно...

Comment: Простите, но где вы усмотрели эвиденциалис... в русском?

Comment: @Aer Как минимум - все безличные предложения среднего рода. Ср. "Деревья были повалены ветром / повалил ветер" и "Деревья повалило ветром". Было ещё что-то, но сейчас я погрузился в санскрит, а из долговременной памяти лень выгружать.

Comment: Ну, в приведенных вами примерах нет разницы типа _я видел — я не видел_. В русском языке если и есть эвиденциальность, то она, во-первых, не грамматикализована, а во-вторых, передается, как правило, лексическими средствами, напр.: «__У меня на глазах__ произошла драка». Но стоит ли это называть _грамматической категорией_ (эвиденциальность)?

Answer (score 1):

**Ответ можно найти в** [лекциях Арзамас](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TNn-or7jjVY).

Если кратко, то как и со всеми языками, так вышло. Заимствовались и сохранялись черты, удобные людям. В русском очень много заимствований.
Далее сравнение с английским (язык, который легко учится иностранцами).

**Английский пошел по пути синтаксического усложнения, а русский по пути морфологического усложнения.**

Разумеется это грубое обобщение, идеализация и вопрос холиварный, но эти признаки на поверхности.

В русском очень простой синтаксис. Можно часто ставить слова почти в любом порядке, но на каждое слово может быть с десяток его форм.

В английском все полностью наоборот. Очень важен синтаксис и от четких правил пляшут все расположения слов, добавления предлогов, форма слов (обычно мало форм, точно не с десяток).

Английский является очень формализованным и структурированный языком, очень легко алгоримизируется и подается легко изучению не только людям, но и машинам. Все по полочкам. Никаких лишних падежей (а раньше было 5).

*Советую посмотреть другие лекции первого сезона и прочие источники*

- https://skyeng.ru/articles/cases-in-english/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q3LezIHm59k
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N9pODcaQGD4
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jDRmG6x6wTw
  и т.д.

Comment: я не филолог, просто посмотрел немного лекций, если есть комментарии по делу, то поправлю отчет.

Comment: А как выбирается порядок слов в русском языке, по каким правилам?  Это ошибка — считать его свободным, а синтаксис очень простым. Может, это как раз и есть то, что иностранцам освоить всего труднее, потому что носители выбирают порядок слов во многом интуитивно А наша сложная морфология на службе у "простого" синтаксиса.

Comment: ну так я не говорю, что это все в абсолюте. В простом предложении можно поставить слова в любом порядке.
"Маша купила 36 мандаринов."

Comment: @Sharon при этом у мандаринов есть 3 формы в зависимости от числа. 31 мандарин, 34 мандарина, 37 мандаринов.

Comment: А как выбрать? Вариантов много, но только один из них соответствует коммуникативной ситуации.  А ваше предложение больше на задачку похоже, чем на реальную ситуацию.

Comment: так что выбор порядка слов в русском точно на много легче, а правильная форма слов - сложная задача для иностранца.

Comment: Уверяю вас, вы заблуждаетесь.  Вы не знаете, что такое порядок слсов в русском языке, как мне кажется.   Там только одна видимость свободы.

Comment: @Sharon пруфы есть?

Comment: Да сколько угодно, каждое предложение можно считать пруфом)  Ключевое понятие - инверсия и логические ударения.  Меняем порядок слов, и все меняется.

Comment: зачем? мне есть чем заняться, я могу почти в каждом предложении в этом треде поменять порядок слов и никакого смысла не потеряется. Это подтверждение. Все эти логические ударения могут быть произнесены голосом.

Comment: если есть, что сказать по существу, я обновлю ответ. холиварить мне лень)

Comment: Возьмите справочник и прочитайте, что такое логические ударения и для чего делается инверсия. На этом и закончим, мне тоже лень вам это объяснять, тем более что без толку. Извините, если что не так.  Вы ведь новый участник, разговаривать с вами нужно вежливо)

Comment: @Sharon 1) обсуждение следует вести в чате. 2) прочитал определение, в основном определение касается речи. Логическое ударение в данном случае - очень слабый аргумент. В предложении про машу слова в русском ставятся в любом порядке. В английском "Masha bought 36 tangerines." другого порядка быть не может.

Comment: Маша купила килограммов 36 мандаринов. Приблизительно 36, не точно. //  Грамматическая связь слов через окончания делает возможной их инверсию. Одно подчинено другому.

Comment: Машинный язык английский — ни уму. ни сердцу.   Хорош для передачи информации.   Современный английский язык — это суржик всех языков мира? Он и изначально вроде был суржиком, но это специалисты должны оценить. Нормандское наречие и английское просторечие? Просто слышала такую версию.

Comment: От того, что в английском другого порядка слов "быть не может", не следует, что в русском языке нет логического по расположению слов и логико-интонационного ударения. Хотя дело скорее в том, что вы слабо понимаете русский и ориентируетесь на еще более слабые знания о переводе бейзик-инглиша на русский. 1) Маша купила 36 мандаринов. 2) Купила Маша 36 мандаринов. 3)36 мандаринов купила Маша и тп,- не эквивалентны. Если переводить на инглиш, то это будет: 1) Masha had bought 36 mandarins; 2) On one occasion, Masha had bought 36 mandarins; 3)There were 36 of mandarins bought by Masha.

Comment: @Буратино нет. 2) Однажды Маша купила 36 мандаринов. 3) 36 мандаринов были куплены Машей. Использование других способов в английском поменяло значение всего предложения.

Comment: @AndrewLouis или даже не так, вот смотри, есть вопросы: сколько мандаринов купила Маша? Как ответить на него? А как ответить на вопрос: кто купил мандарины и сколько? Порядок вопросов определяет расположение слов в ответе. Если человек на вопрос сколько? начинает ответ со слова Маша - значит он не понимает о чём идет речь скорее всего. То есть русский язык исходит не из позиционирования - statement, то есть всяких фактов и признаков, а из предположения о вопросе, на который отвечает говорящий. Русский язык двухуровневый. А теперь придумай вопрос к фразе: купила Маша 46 мандаринов.

Answer (score 0):

Действительно, миф о сверхсложности придумали, видимо, те, которые не могут изучить язык. Русский ничто по сравнению с японским. Там, в отличии от русского, мелодичная интонация, и от повышения-понижения голоса меняется смысл слова. Эта одна из сложностей. В испанском языке, например, тоже есть спряжение глаголов, и, конечно же, множество неправильных глаголов, спряжение которых надо заучивать наизусть. Это тоже трудность. А артикли? Это разве не трудность? Армянский тоже очень сложный. А насчет грамматики итальянского и латинского, то скажу - они очень похожи. Вообще латинский, испанский, итальянский очень похожи. Как, например, русский, украинский, белорусский.

Comment: >>Русский ничто по сравнению с японским.

 Фраза звучит как минимум некорректно.

Comment: А мне японский, по крайней мере, в плане грамматики и разговорной речи, кажется проще русского. Там основная сложность (для меня, по крайней мере) в иероглифах.  
А испанский - да.  
Хотя русский берет еще и зверской пунктуацией. ))))

Comment: Кажется, русский - пример мелодичности для прочих языков.

Comment: Похоже, вы путаете японский и китайский.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что наш русский язык действительно очень сложен. Достаточно лишь взглянуть на размер некоторых слов и их произношение, несмотря уже на грамматику. Правописание наречий, которые пишутся не то через дефис, не то слитно, а не то раздельно. Это тоже нужно зубрить. Даже большинство русских не знают грамматики на сто процентов. А что говорить об оборотах, постоянно выделяющихся бесконечным количеством запятых? А ещё не забывайте про элементы агглютинации с постфиксом -ся-. Например, слово "драться" не значит по смыслу "драть себя", хотя дословно так и складывается.

Answer (score 0):

```
ИЗ КОММЕНТАРИЕВ

В русском очень простой синтаксис. Можно часто ставить слова 
почти в любом порядке... Я могу почти в каждом предложении в 
этом треде поменять порядок слов и никакого смысла не 
потеряется. 

Действительно, миф о сверхсложности придумали, видимо, те, 
которые не могут изучить язык. Русский ничто по сравнению с 
японским. Там, в отличии от русского, мелодичная интонация, 
и от повышения-понижения голоса меняется смысл слова.
```

**О "простом" синтаксисе и "свободном"  порядке слов на примере простого предложения**

1. Рассмотрим действительно простое предложение,  всего-то из четырех слов:

*Артамоновы жИли  / **ни с кем ни знакОмясь**.*

Оно делится на две части произносительной паузой (тема и рема), а интонационно это две **фонетические фразы**: повышение и понижение тона на ударном слоге. При нейтральной интонации движение тона делается **на последнем слове фразы**. Нормальный **порядок** для предикативной основы: Артамоновы жИли (подлежащее + сказуемое).

2. Но в авторском тексте использована **инверсия:**

*Жили  Артамоновы  / **ни с кем ни знакОмясь**.*

Зачем она нужна?  – Так свободный же порядок порядок слов. –
**Не такой уж  он свободный!** Это авторский выбор, причем намеренный. Нарушен **нормальный**  порядок слов в основе (сказуемое + подлежащее)  и интонация перестала быть **нейтральной.** Фразовое ударение перемещается на первое слово и становится **логическим.** Слово выделено,  но это не силовое выделение, а всего лишь **смещение** фразового ударения.

Всего-то одно слово переставили, и так много перемен!  **Смысл** вроде бы не изменился, понять можно, но **стилистика нехороша**. Не по-русски звучит и привлекает внимание к такой речи. Гармонии и сладкозвучия не хватает) И это всего лишь пример простейшего предложения.

3. Весь синтаксис построен на этом. Свободный порядок слов  делает возможным  размещение слова в **ударной** позиции предложения, где оно будет логически **подчеркнуто.** И делается это по слуху, **интуитивно**, носители языка  не задумываются над выбором ( у них чувство языка).  Каждое предложение имеет тот **порядок** слов, который необходим в **конкретной** ситуации.
4. А как это изучают **не носители языка?**  Трудно сказать, а изучить, вероятно, еще труднее.  Свобода выбора всегда хуже, чем жесткий порядок.  Каждый вариант **правилен на своем месте**, а если они кажутся похожими, то что  тогда делать?  Поэтому сложен русский язык для изучения. Да и синтаксис у него необычный, как и необычна его история.
5. **Необычный и сложный!** Стоит, к примеру, взглянуть на систему **взаимообусловленных отношений** в сложном предложении. Вам на выбор три основные **модели: ССП, СПП, БСП**, они могут быть синонимичными.
6. Теперь посмотрим на **сложноподчиненное** предложение. Одна только классификация чего стоит! В школе дается упрощенный вариант, но его приходится дополнять вузовским материалом. А иначе разбор не сделаешь и знаки не поставишь.
7. Но зато как все красиво, какой удивительный **порядок** можно увидеть, если все же разобраться! Стандартные модели, элементы фразеологии – все это отражено в предложениях этого вида.
8. А в БСП **союзов нет**, поэтому подчинительные отношения выражены **интонацией**. Но тогда вам придется изучать русскую интонацию, а это о-очень непросто. Но зато вы поймете **МЕЛОДИКУ** русской речи, которой будто бы нет.

Вот такой у нас **простой** синтаксис и **свободный** порядок слов в предложении.

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ**

Несколько слов об истории русского языка **[из статьи](https://rvb.ru/pushkin/01text/07criticism/01criticism/0124_30/0914.htmhttps://).**

Вот как об этом рассказывает величайшей наш поэт А.С. Пушкин.

*«…он богат, сладкозвучен и обилен разнообразными оборотами. Как материал словесности, язык славяно-русский имеет **неоспоримое превосходство** пред всеми европейскими: судьба его была **чрезвычайно счастлива.** В XI веке древний греческий язык вдруг открыл ему свой лексикон, сокровищницу гармонии, даровал ему **законы обдуманной своей грамматики**, свои прекрасные **обороты,** величественное течение речи; словом, **усыновил его,** избавя таким образом от медленных усовершенствований времени. Сам по себе уже **звучный и выразительный**, отселе заемлет он **гибкость и правильность**.  Простонародное наречие необходимо должно было отделиться от книжного; но впоследствии они **сблизились,** и такова стихия, данная нам для сообщения наших мыслей».*