# Место местоимения я в перечислении

Tags: местоимения

Как правильно говорить, «*я с кем-то*» или «*кто-то и я*»? Например, «я с подругой и мужем ходила в кино» или «подруга, муж и я ходили в кино»? Основной вопрос: можно ли по правилам местоимение **я** ставить на первое место?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 2):

**Можно** ставить "я" на первое место (обратная последовательность более типична для английского), но есть и другой вариант: "***мы*** с подругой и мужем ходили..." Вариант с "я" подчёркивает собственную роль в описании мероприятия и подходит для контекста, где вы говорите, напр., только о своих впечатлениях и больше не упоминаете о своих спутниках; вариант с "мы" более нейтрален. Если вы выбираете вариант с "я", то если вы ходили туда *вместе* с кем-то (а не порознь и не в разное время), вместо "*я и кто-то ещё...*" естественнее выбрать "**я с кем-то ходила**" (это меньше похоже на перевод с другого языка).

Answer (score 2):

Обычно используются следующие сочетания:  **я с кем-то, мы с кем-то,** реже ― **я и кто-то.** Вариант **кто-то и я** практически не употребляется.

1) Если вы рассказываете (отвечаете на вопрос) **о себе**, то используется форма **я с кем-то, я и кто-то:**

В начале июля **я с подругой** улетела на 2 недели на Кипр, после Кипра я его больше не видела. **Я и муж** ничего этого в детстве не имели.

1) Если вы рассказываете **о семье, о друзьях**, то  используется форма **мы с кем-то:**

**Мы с подругой** решили пойти на танцы в клуб. **Мы с мужем** едем на море, а ребенок остаётся под присмотром бабушки. **Мы с мужем** перестраивали этот дом много лет.

Answer (score 1):

Разумеется. Вот примеры употребления:

В. Г. Короленко, "В дурном обществе", заглавие "[Я и мой отец](https://ilibrary.ru/text/1764/p.3/index.html)".

"[Я и друг мой грузовик](https://www.discogs.com/artist/777052-%D0%AF-%D0%B8-%D0%94%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%93%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA)" (название музыкального альбома)

"[Я и другие](https://www.kinopoisk.ru/film/ya-i-drugie-1971-474668/)" (название фильма, 1971)

"[Я и Ты](http://lib.ru/FILOSOF/BUBER/ihunddu1.txt_with-big-pictures.html)" (работа философа Мартина Бубера).

Вариант "я с кем-то" является также правильным, ближе к разговорному стилю. Встречается как частный случай [финно-угорского субстрата в русском](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/41849/%D0%9E-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0/431400#431400) (калька с [сопроводительного падежа](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2)).

Глагол в русском языке нередко [эллиптичен](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81), поэтому его наличие или отсутствие не принципиально.

Comment: Вопрос был поставлен о сочетании с глаголом, а не о перечислении в заголовке - это разные вещи. Попробуйте соединить с глаголом "Я и мой грузовик...".

Comment: `Я и мой грузовик давно прокляли тот день, когда я сел за баранку этого пылесоса...`

Comment: @Alex_ander Глагол в русском языке эллиптичен, так что его наличие не очень отличается от отсутствия, а заголовок - от предложения.

Comment: А почему конструкции типа _я с кем-то_ — «частный случай финно-угорского субстрата»?

Comment: @Aer потому что такая последовательность (номинатив плюс комитатив) характерна именно для финно-угорских языков. Для сравнения: конструкции наподобе "Никита, Стас, Гена, Турбо и Дюша Метёлкин - со мной" для финно-угорских языков не характерны.

Comment: И что, что она характерна? Это не основания для констатации связи русской конструкции с финно-угорской.

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендаций в справочниках найти не удалось. Однако при выборе двух конструкций следует иметь в виду, что сочетание с предлогом **с + творительный падеж** указывают на **совместность  действия.** Такова семантика предлога с. Конструкции же с **союзом и** указывают на равноправность действий.  Так, например, предложение «Я и мой друг пошли гулять» не обязательно означает,  что мы ходили вместе. В целом можно отметить, для русского языка более характерны конструкции с предлогом с.